# Saved files in public folder are visible, but not accessible by PC

Tags: android, save, android-external-storage

[Folder-not-accessible-on-PC: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuKdy.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuKdy.png]

I want to save sensor data to a public folder in the external storage. Thereby the folder is just visible, but not accessible by PC as shown in the attached image. On Android I can access the data without any problem.

I really do not know the problem, since I have granted the permissions for external storage, tried the "ExternalStorageDirectory" and the "ExternalStoragePublicDirectory" and added the MediaScanner after the closing of the FileWriters. Furthermore, I tried the MediaScanner in two different ways: One time, it scanned the folder, one time it scanned the sensor file. Nothing worked.

Therefore, I would be very very thankful, if you could give me a hint, why I cannot access the folder by PC. Thank you very much in advance!

To sum up - I have tried this:
- ExternalStorageDirectory
- ExternalStoragePublicDirectory
- MediaScanner scanning the file 
- MediaScanner scanning the folder
- I also tried to follow this question: [Saving public files in android but folders are not accessible by PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019710/saving-public-files-in-android-but-folders-are-not-accessible-by-pc)

````
FileWriter GPSwriter;
File f;

//Check if external storage is available

private boolean isExternalStorageWritable(){
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
Log.i("state", "Yes, it is writable");
return true;
} else {
return false;
}

//Create Folder

myfolder = "Logger";
f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), myfolder);

f.setExecutable(true);
f.setReadable(true);
f.setWritable(true);

if (!f.exists()) {
   f.mkdirs()
} else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pfad " + myfolder + " existiert bereits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//Filewriter

GPSwriter.write(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%d,%d\n", curGPStime, curLat, curLong, curAlt, curSpeed, curBearing, curHorzAcc, curBearAcc, curSpeedAcc, curVertAcc, curElaTime, curGPStimenull));

//Create file

if (isExternalStorageWritable()){

 GPSwriter = new FileWriter(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString() + "/" + myfolder,"Location.csv"));

try{
GPSwriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


//Scan Media to see the files -> When I scan "f" I can see the folder at least, when I just scan the file, I cannot see anything at all //

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{f.toString()}, null, null);```
````

Comment: Is the file created without writing anything in the file writer? I see you are creating a folder yourself but you are not creating csv file and I guess the file writer is not creating the file untill we write anything in it just check once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually, there is something written into the file, but I forgot to share it here. On the phone I can access and read the csv-file with the sensor data, but I cannot access it on the PC. When I am going to copy the data manually on the phone into another folder of the phone, I can access it on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue!

I guess the problem was, that the file was created within a protected class. I moved it forward to the beginning of the program and now it is working :)

Best!